# Nested SQL IN statement for cell with more than 1 value

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

[image]

[image]

How do i write the SQL such that it will return me

`tom,ken,jerry`

I tried this SQL as

```
select name
  from staffDB
 where dept in (select value 
                  from ConfigDB 
                 where key = 'dept')
```

but it returns no value, no nope, i'm not allowed to alter the database design.

Answer (score 0):

Your database design is not optimal, because it is storing CSV values.  That being said, here is one way to get the output you want using `LISTAGG` (11g+):

```
SELECT
    c."Key",
    LISTAGG(s.Name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.Dept) Departments
FROM ConfigDB c
LEFT JOIN StaffDB s
    ON ',' || c."Value" || ',' LIKE '%,' || s.Dept || '%,'
GROUP BY
    c."Key";
```

### Demo

Note that we compare the CSV list of departments in the config table to each scalar value in the staff table using this logic, for example:

```
,A,B,C, LIKE '%,A,%'
```

That is, we tag on commas onto the CSV string of departments, so that we may search for each possible scalar department surrounded by commas.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be splitting by commas, an then combining through use of `LISTAGG()` function within `SELECT .. CONNECT BY level ..` Statement :

```
WITH ConfigDB( key, value ) AS
(
 SELECT 'dept', 'A,B,C' FROM dual
), StaffDB( name, dept ) AS
(
 SELECT 'tom'  , 'A' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'ken'  , 'B' FROM dual UNION ALL
 SELECT 'jerry', 'C' FROM dual  
), t AS
(
 SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value,'[^,]',1,level) AS letter, level AS lvl
   FROM ConfigDB
  CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(value,',') + 1
)
SELECT LISTAGG(name,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY lvl) AS DBNAme
  FROM t  
  JOIN StaffDB
    ON dept = letter
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=022a8d44611f15e98ffa41138ab74f77)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select * from 
(select LISTAGG(Name, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Dept) as name, 
LISTAGG(Dept, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Dept) as dept from staffDB)
where dept  in
(select value from ConfigDB);
```

Below is the Test Case,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the hierarchy query to split the value and then join it as follows:

```
SQL>  SELECT
2      C.KEY,
3      LISTAGG(S.NAME, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY S.DEPT) DEPARTMENTS
4     FROM
5      CONFIGDB   C
6      CROSS JOIN TABLE ( CAST(MULTISET(
7          SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(C.VALUE, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)
8            FROM DUAL
9          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(C.VALUE, '[^,]+')
10      ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST) ) C1
11      LEFT JOIN STAFFDB    S ON S.DEPT = C1.COLUMN_VALUE
12    GROUP BY C.KEY;

KEY   DEPARTMENTS
----- ---------------
dept  tom,ken,jerry

SQL>
```